# Word for symbolic procedure with little purpose?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

For example, I am taking an online Calculus test because of Covid-19 that would normally be taken in person.

The in-person test requires photo IDs to be checked of all test takers to make sure they are the ones taking the test.

Because of this rule, we must upload our ID online at any point during the week before the test. Effectively making the process redundant but still in effect for the sake of keeping the rules.

I was wondering if there is a word that can be used to describe such a rule?

Thanks!

EDIT: After further thought I think 'a formality' would be a good phrase to describe this.

Comment: I think you face a positive embarrassment of choices for that. As Richard Armour wrote in introducing Paul Tabori’s *The Natural Science of Stupidity,* “What can be more characteristic of our mankind than the fact that Roget’s *Thesaurus* devotes six columns to the synonyms, verbs, nouns, and adjectives of ‘stupidity’ while ‘wisdom’ occupies hardly one?”

Comment: _Ritual_ is the normal term.

Comment: Not sure why you're calling the process redundant. Seems like a straightforward extension of the requirement for identity verification for in-person tests to online tests. Where is the redundancy?  Is there a requirement that you provide your photo ID more than once?

Comment: A "waste of time" or "useless activity"?

Comment: @RichardKayser, "Redundant" isn't the right word, but "useless" or "ineffective" would apply. Uploading your ID days before an exam does nothing to prove that the person who actually answered the exam questions is the one whose ID was shown.

Comment: @ThePhoton Excellent point. I was simply responding to the OP's use of *redundant* and the associated flaw in the wording of the question. I hope the OP will edit the question based on this exchange.

Comment: It really depends on how the test is administered.  If you had to take the test while on a video conference then the proctor could look at you on video and compare to the uploaded ID.  For example.

Answer (score 3):

A symbolic procedure with little real purpose:

*pro forma*

Wikipedia explains pro forma as follows:

> The term pro forma (Latin for "as a matter of form" or "for the sake of form") is most often used to describe a practice or document that is provided as a courtesy or satisfies minimum requirements, conforms to a norm or doctrine, tends to be performed perfunctorily or is considered a formality.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_forma

Comment: You got it. I was going to suggest *Verifiable* so the one who signs up actually can be proved to be taking the test.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a **check-the-box** *exercise*. From the Urban Dictionary:

> **[check the box](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=check%20the%20box)**: A phrase which means to complete a task to the barest minimum standard, and subsequently cease working. At this point one may check off the box on a task list or matrix.

Whoever is administering your online calculus test has created a **check-the-box** requirement that creates the illusion that they have identity verification and cheating prevention under control, when in reality they don't. It's a meaningless exercise, or as you so aptly put it, "a symbolic procedure with little purpose."

Answer (score 0):

The organization has a [**CYA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass) in place to cover their asses for the potential failure of this practice.  Unfortunately, it doesn't matter how effective these measures are just as long as they are in place.

> According to The New York Times' language expert William Safire, it
> describes "the bureaucratic technique of averting future accusations
> of policy error or wrongdoing by deflecting responsibility in
> advance". It often involves diffusing responsibility for one's
> actions as a form of insurance against possible future negative
> repercussions. It can denote a type of institutional risk-averse
> mentality which works against accountability and responsibility, **often
> characterized by excessive paperwork and documentation,** which can be harmful to the institution's overall effectiveness.

Of course, you are uploading your ID to cover your ass also, and it ultimately serves the same bureaucratic "purpose."

Answer (score 0):

This can be called **theater**. The most common usage is **security theater** as in “The TSA’s job is not security, it’s security theater”.  See https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/01/tsa-business-security-theater-not-security/357599/